# QCD string breaking and glueballs

Tags: quantum-field-theory

When one tries to pull two quarks appart, a flux tube is created.
The tube eventually breaks, creating quark anti-quark pairs and eventually hadrons.

Can there also be creation of gluons to form glueballs?
Does this happen at a higher or lower energy then hadron creation?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of flux tube breaking is that the two "old" quarks form new flux tubes with each of the "new" ones, resulting in two pairs of quarks. If flux tube breaking created gluons instead, that would mean that the "old" quarks are now unpaired, i.e. free. But this is not consistent with the principle of confinement: all finite energy states in quantum chromodynamics should be singlets under the global $SU(3)$ group; this rules out free quarks. Therefore the situation you describe is prohibited.